# Identityserver4 Use Two Same External Provider,The Second External Provider Login Always failed

Tags: identityserver4, discord.net

I use two discord provider with different clientid for login.The code below:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddDiscord("ADiscord", u =>
                {
                    u.ClientId = "74627xxx8536";
                    u.ClientSecret = "B-FLxxxxjp3JOKwr27";
                    u.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    u.Scope.Add("guilds.join");
                    u.SaveTokens = true;
                    u.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
                    u.CorrelationCookie.IsEssential = true;
                })
                .AddDiscord("BDiscord", u =>
                {
                    u.ClientId = "71475xxx1925";
                    u.ClientSecret = "45-xxxA4okXx1I";
                    u.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    u.Scope.Add("guilds.join");
                    u.SaveTokens = true;
                    u.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
                    u.CorrelationCookie.IsEssential = true;
                });
```

When i login with scheme "ADiscord" everything is ok.But use scheme "BDiscord" it throw an error "**Error from RemoteAuthentication: The oauth state was missing or invalid**".
What's even more strange is that if change the order let "BDiscord" on the top then login with scheme "BDiscord" everything is ok,"ADiscord" will throw the error.

Disord provider code is on **https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Discord**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [CallbackPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.remoteauthenticationoptions.callbackpath?view=aspnetcore-3.1), set it to sth like `/signin-discord` and register `/signin-discord` with the IdSvr4. This endpoint is used to complete the OAuth handshake before redirecting to an application endpoint.

Comment: OMG....It is worked ..I was obsessed with this problem for two days..thx